# Vue MultiSelect change pointer class display

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I'm trying to find out how to change the html/css of the "pointer" part of vue-multiselect, e.g. https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-props (showPointer)

For smaller screens the text "Press enter to select" is obscuring the value. So I'm trying to either remove the text or create my own hovering html/css.

[image]

Here's what it looks like on larger screens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `showLabels` props from vue-multiselect documentation. `showLabels` props has Boolean values `true` or `false`. If `false` then no pointer hover value will be shown. There have five custom props for controlling hover value like

- selectLabel
- selectGroupLabel
- selectedLabel
- deselectLabel
- deselectGroupLabel

You should write `show-labels` props when implementing these props.

You can check this example from JsFiddle:
[https://jsfiddle.net/sukantabala28/](https://jsfiddle.net/sukantabala28/fbros7ga/8/)